# How is spark dealing with driver memory? It is using more space then allocated

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

[image]

how it is possible that storage memory (of driver) which is limited by 5.2g as shown in image, is exceeded by spark to 36.5g?

How does this memory allocation takes place? does spark use disk apart from RAM by default settings? As indicated in UI it uses 16.5g of disc space (What is the limit on disk space use?).

Answer (score 0):

**Your first question:**

> How does this memory allocation takes place? does spark use disk apart from RAM by default settings?

Yes. Please read about block manager [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-blockmanager.html). As it points out,

> BlockManager manages the storage for blocks that can represent cached RDD partitions, intermediate shuffle outputs, broadcasts, etc. It is also a BlockEvictionHandler that drops a block from memory and storing it on a disk if applicable.

**Your second question:**

> What is the limit on disk space use?

As far as I know, there is no limit. Executors start dying if they don't have enough space. You can refer [this](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/277/how-do-i-avoid-the-no-space-left-on-device-error.html) for more details.